# UITableViewCell Unrecognized Selector To Instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with the following code in cellForRow

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    SettingsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[SettingsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.avatarPhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frownFace.png"];

    return cell;
}
```

In SettingsTableViewCell I have avatarPhoto declared as the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *avatarPhoto;
```

My storyboard connection looks like so:

```
http://cl.ly/image/3k1N3e0c2V2w
```

For some reason, I am getting the following error when attaching an image to my UIImageView:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell avatarPhoto]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Any ideas?

EDITS

My cell identifiers are structured the following way with an NSArray:

```
  self.items = @[@"Cell", @"firstSep", @"accountManagement", @"realName", @"secondSep", @"friends", @"find", @"inviteText", @"inviteViaEmail", @"thirdSep", @"more", @"feedback", @"terms", @"privacy", @"attribution", @"footerSep"];
```

This is how my Cell looks in storyboards:

```
http://cl.ly/image/0d3L3E2W3E1n
```

Comment: cellIdentifier, are you putting the same one which you register for your settingsTableViewCell ? try dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: and before that register your settingsTableViewCell to a reusableidentifier

Comment: The cell identifier should identify the generic cell type.  In general, this means it's somehow tied to the cell's class.  (Eg, it could be the literal @"SettingsTableViewCell".)  You SHOULD NOT have a unique one for each cell.

Answer (score 1):

As error says `-[UITableViewCell avatarPhoto]:` so you are getting `UITableViewCell`  not `SettingsTableViewCell` instance while dequeing cells.Check the class in storyboard

Go to `attribute inspector` and than select `cell` and give `cell identifier` and `cell class name`

[image]

[image]

```
SettingsTableViewCell *cell = (SettingsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Also you do not need to write

```
 if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[SettingsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` gurantees to give instance of cell if not available.

Comment: Hey. I am using identifiers via an NSArray. Each Cell has it's own identifier. The UITableView loads fine with the right elements. Labels are working too. It's just with the image.

Comment: david, you are not using the instance of settingTableViewCell, instead you are getting instance of UITableViewCell

Comment: @davidTurner For all cell do you have set your class verify and also check forall cells do you have outlets connection

Comment: Have you checked your class name as error clearly says `-[UITableViewCell avatarPhoto]:` UITableViewCell check class in story board

Comment: If you use unique identifiers for each cell like that you will use too much storage and get sluggish performance.

Comment: Yes truly agree with @HotLicks. davidTurner if you have same cells then reuse the cells with single identifier.It improves performance.

Comment: I do not have the same cells, hence why I am doing this.

Comment: @davidTurner have you checked class names you are doing something wrong because of that you are getting `UITableViewCell` instance instead of `SettingTableViewCell`

Comment: Codester do you have a Skype where we can easily talk?

Comment: @davidTurner - Trust me, you're doing it wrong.  You supposedly only have the SettingTableViewCell, so you should only need one cell identifier.

Comment: If not, yes I did check. I'm not sure why I am getting UITableViewCell. I have it marked as SettingsTableViewCell with the identifier of Cell. Should I have my UIImage on top of that?

Comment: Hot Licks, I have 10 cells with different identifiers and all of them are working completely fine with custom labels and images. For some reason, this cell is the one giving me an issue.

Comment: See the images I've packaged here: http://cl.ly/1u352P0A3G2Q - All the other cells work fine. For some reason the app crashes when I add the image, that's it.

Comment: @davidTurner - In other words, "I'm doing it wrong but it *almost* works, so why should I correct any obvious errors?"